# how to make regexp not hungry with quotes?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

how to make it not hungry - `preg_match_all('/"[\p{L}\p{Nd}а-яА-ЯёЁ -_\.\+]+"/ui', $outStr, $matches);`

Comment: I believe the general term is 'lazy'

Comment: @josh: Actually, it's "greedy".

Comment: Actually, terms like *greedy* and *lazy* are only colloquial shortcuts for longer and more technical terms, shortcuts which can sometimes mask what is really happening. The more technical terms are that quantifiers can match *maximally*, *minimally*, or *possessively*, where `*`, `+`, `?`, and `{n,m}` are the **maximal set**; `*?`, `+?`, `??`, and `{n,m}?` are the **minimal set**; and `*+`, `++`, and `{n,m}+` are the **possessive set**. Plus I suppose `?+` for completeness’ sake, but it doesn’t change what it does: think about it. 

Comment: @Tomalak: I believe I said it correctly - 'not hungry' == 'lazy'. I think you were thinking 'hungry' == 'greedy'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean non-greedy, as in find the shortest match instead of the longest? The `*`, `+`, and `?` quantifiers are greedy by default and will match as much as possible. Add a question mark after them to make them non-greedy.

```
preg_match_all('/"[\p{L}\p{Nd}а-яА-ЯёЁ -_\.\+]+?"/ui', $outStr, $matches);
```

Greedy match:

```
"foo" and "bar"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Non-greedy match:

```
"foo" and "bar"
^^^^^
```

Comment: Yeap thanks I`d tried to set ? symbol after ", but it didn`t work well.

Answer (score 3):

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

> U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)
>
> This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the quantifiers so
>   that they are not greedy by default,
>   but become greedy if followed by ?. It
>   is not compatible with Perl. It can
>   also be set by a (?U) modifier setting
>   within the pattern or by a question
>   mark behind a quantifier (e.g. .*?).

Comment: Oops!  That means PHP and Java use the `(?U)` flag differently. In PHP it turns on the `PCRE_UNGREEDY` regex compile flag, but in JDK7 it turns on `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` regex compile flag to make character classes conform to the [spec on Unicode regexes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) — which is something PHP already does by default (I believe!), since Perl already does. Hm, reading  the *pcrepattern* manpage leaves me mildly suspicious. It looks like it is only `[\pL\pN_]`, which isn’t quite what RL1.2 cited above wants. But it’s better than ASCII.

Comment: generally a bad idea to use U (flip the quantifier behavior) unless you really know what you're doing. It is a lot more clear and gives you more control to flip it for each one individually using ?

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Comment: Note, the `(?U)` modifier is [_unique_](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to PCRE (and derivatives like PHP and R) and won't be found in e.g. JavaScript, Python, or Perl.  An earlier comment noted it behaves completely differently in Java.

Answer (score 2):

ou suggested

```
/"[\p{L}\p{Nd}а-яА-ЯёЁ -_\.\+]+"/ui
```

which I submit is equivalent to:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd}а-яА-ЯёЁ -_.+]+"/ui
```

To show people which non-ASCII you’re using in case it is not obvious,
using `\x{⋯}` escapes that is:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd}\x{430}-\x{44F}\x{410}-\x{42F}\x{451}\x{401} -_.+]+"/ui
```

And using named characters is:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd}\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A}-\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YA}\N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A}-\N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YA}\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IO}\N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IO} -_.+]+"/ui
```

BTW, those are produced by running them through the [*uniquote* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniquote), the first using `uniquote -x` and the second using `uniquote -v`.

And yes, I know or at least believe that PHP doesn’t support named characters yet, but it makes it easier to talk about.  Also, it makes sure they don't confuse the lookalikes:

```
U+0410 ‹А› \N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A}
U+0430 ‹а› \N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A}
U+0401 ‹Ё› \N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IO}
U+0451 ‹ё› \N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IO}
```

for:

```
U+0041 ‹A› \N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A}
U+0061 ‹a› \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}
U+00CB ‹Ë› \N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS}
U+00EB ‹ë› \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS}
```

And now I think about it, those are all letters, so I cannot not see why you are enumerating the Cyrillic list. It is because
you don’t want *all* Cyrillic letters, but rather just that particular set of them?  Otherwise I would just do:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd} -_.+]+"/ui
```

At which point I wonder about that `/i`.    I can’t see what its purpose is, so would just write:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd} -_.+]+"/u
```

As has been mentioned, swapping the maximally quantifying `+` for its corresponding minimal version, `+?`, will work:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd} -_.+]+?"/u
```

However, I am concerned about that range of `[ -_]`, that is, `\p{SPACE}-\p{LOW LINE}`.
I find that a very peculiar range.  It means any of these

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
```

For one thing, you’ve included the capital ASCII letters again.  For another, you’ve omitted some symbols and punctuation characters:

```
% unichars -g '\p{ASCII}' '[\pS\pP]' 'ord() < ord(" ") || ord() > ord("_")'
 `  U+0060 GC=Sk GRAVE ACCENT
 {  U+007B GC=Ps LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 |  U+007C GC=Sm VERTICAL LINE
 }  U+007D GC=Pe RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ~  U+007E GC=Sm TILDE
```

(That output is from the [*unichars* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars), in case you’re curious.)

Which seems strangely arbitrary.  So I’m wondering whether this might not be good enough for you:

```
/"[\pL\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP]+?"/u
```

Now that I think about it, these two might cause other problems:

```
U+0401 ‹Ё› \N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IO}
U+0451 ‹ё› \N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IO}
```

That assumes those are in NFC form (formed by canonical composition of a canonical decomposition). If there were a chance that you are dealing with data that hasn’t been normalized to NFC form, then you would have to account for

```
NFD("\N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IO}") => "\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE}\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}"
NFD("\N{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IO}")   => "\N{CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER IE}\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}"
```

And now you have non-letters!    The

```
% uniprops "COMBINING DIAERESIS"
U+0308 ‹◌̈› \N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}
    \w \pM \p{Mn}
    All Any Assigned InCombiningDiacriticalMarks Case_Ignorable CI Combining_Diacritical_Marks Dia Diacritic M Mn Gr_Ext Grapheme_Extend Graph GrExt ID_Continue IDC Inherited Zinh Mark Nonspacing_Mark Print Qaai Word XID_Continue XIDC
```

So maybe you would actually want:

```
/"[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP]+?"/u
```

If you wanted to restrict your string to containing only characters that are from the Latin or Cyrillic scripts (and not, say, Greek or Katakana), then you would add a lookahead to that effect:

```
/"(?:(?=[\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}])[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP])+?"/u
```

Except that you also need `Common` to get the digits and various puntuation and symbols, and
you need `Inherited` for combining marks following your letters.  That brings us up to this:

```
/"(?:(?=[\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}])[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP])+?"/u
```

That now suggests another way to effect a minimal match between the double quotes:

```
/"(?:(?!")(?=[\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}])[\pL\pM\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP])+"/u
```

Which is getting way complicated not to run in `/x` mode:

```
/
    "               # literal double quote
    (?:
  ### This group specifies a single char with
  ### three separate constraints:

        # Constraint 1: next char must NOT be a double quote
        (?!")

        # Constraint 2: next char must be from one of these four scripts
        (?=[\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}])

        # Constraint 3: match one of either Letter, Mark, Decimal Number,
        #               whitespace, Symbol, or Punctuation:
        [\pL\pM\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP]

    )       # end constraint group
    +       # repeat entire group 1 or more times
    "       # and finally match another double-quote
/ux
```

If it were Perl, I would write that with `m{⋯}xu`

```
m{
    "               # literal double quote
    (?:
  ### This group specifies a single char with
  ### three separate constraints:

        # Constraint 1: next char must NOT be a double quote
        (?!")

        # Constraint 2: next char must be from one of these four scripts
        (?=[\p{Latin}\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}])

        # Constraint 3: match one of either Letter, Mark, Decimal Number,
        #               whitespace, Symbol, or Punctuation:
        [\pL\pM\p{Nd}\s\pS\pP]

    )       # end constraint group
    +       # repeat entire group 1 or more times
    "       # and finally match another double-quote
}ux
```

But I do not know whether you can do paired, bracketing delimiters like that in PHP.

Hope this helps!